# Does GAS have anything that evaluates similar to NASM's $ token?

Tags: assembly, nasm, gnu-assembler, binutils

I just started down the Assembly road, and one of the first "Hello, World!" tutorials I found http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/hello.html, gives a nice way of psudo-dynamicly getting the length of the string to enter into the system call.

```
section .data
msg db 'Hello, World!",0xa
len equ $ - msg
```

This works great in nasm, and everything assembles, links, and runs with out question.

The problem comes when I try to find a way to do the same thing in gas.

I understand that the $ in this case is a token that evaluates to the current assembly position http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~comp03/nasm/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.5

Can this expression ($ - msg) be expressed in gas, or is this nasm exclusive syntactic sugar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For x86, you can use "`.`" in the same way.  e.g.

```
    .data

msg:
    .ascii "Hello, World!"
    .byte 0xa
    .equ len, . - msg
```

(Note: this is not necessarily true for other platforms.  `gas` supports many platforms, and various aspects of syntax vary between them!)

Comment: That did exactly what I needed.